# Wildcards using .htaccess to redirect to index page

Tags: htaccess

How do I modify the `.httaccess` to redirect all wild cards to the main domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of pattern are you trying to redirect?

Redirecting subdomains should be done through DNS zone settings. But if you are trying to redirect everyone trying to access a test folder on your server like this: http://jean.org/test/* the following rules would probably work and redirect them to index.php:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /index.php
```

I am not sure if this is the desired behaviour.